# jScrollPane setup

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I've just found this jScrollPane plugin, trying to get it set up and working on my page. On my page I have an outer div

```
< div id="myList" class="scroll-pane" >
```

that wraps multiple other divs - each of the inner divs is essentially one row on the screen with 3 input fields in it. So when the screen first loads, the server side creates enough divs to show the existing records from the db. Then after the page is rendered, I use javascript to create one extra div (row) with empty input fields for data entry. Here's the css for class 'scroll-pane':

```
.scroll-pane {
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's my jScrollPane setup - this is in $(document).ready(function() --
it is simply this:

```
$('#myList').jScrollPane();
```

the next thing in  $(document).ready() is where I add the new div with empty inputs. In there, I patterned it after the example I saw in the docs, so it looks like this:

```
    var newItemHTML = '<div> .... </div>';
    var newItem = $(newItemHTML);
    var pane = $('#myList');
    pane.jScrollPane();
    var api = pane.data('jsp');
    api.getContentPane().append(newItem);
    api.reinitialise();
    api.scrollToBottom();
```

So I'm putting the scroll bar on the myList div, and my goal here is to get it to always show the bottom div (row of empty inputs), scrolling to do that if necessary. 
Here's the things that I'm seeing that I'd like to correct:

1. When the page appears, the javascript to add the last div did work, but instead of that new div appearing immediately below the original last div, the new div goes all the way to the bottom, which is not visible at this point. The only way I can make it appear is by tabbing through fields until I get to it. I can't scroll to it.
2. The scrolling behavior seems odd. First off, there is no visible thumb. I can drag an imaginary thumb up and down which initiates some scrolling, but what happens is that the clump of divs (rows) at the top all jump down to the bottom, leaving a vertical gap at the top.
3. When I use the verticalGutter property to try to move the scrollbar closer in to the actual edge of the content, the scrollbar doesn't move - it stretches my content over so the right edge is closer to the scrollbar.

Frustrating. I think maybe I'm missing something fundamental here with this? Any help most appreciated!  (Oh yeah - I'm using Chrome 17.0.963.83)

Brian